# SyntaxError - Can't Assign to Function Call

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I want to add a `.lower()` call, so instead of doing the following:

```
variable_name = input()
if variable_name == "example" or variable_name == "Example":
    print ("whatever I want")
```

I want to do this

```
variable_name.lower() = input()
if variable_name == "example":
    print ("whatever I want")
```

The problem is, whenever I do this and run the program, it tells me it can't assign to a function call. I have left a section of the code for you to look at.

```
#Variables and Imports Declerations
import sys
import os
awnser.lower() = " "
score = 0
#----------------------------------

while playagin == "yes":

    #Welcome Message and Title
    print ("GeneralQuiz")
    print ("Welcome to GeneralQuiz!")

    #Question 1
    print ("What is the 10th letter of the alphabet?")
    answer.lower() = input ()

    if answer == "j":
        print ("Congratulations! + 1 Score!")
        score = score +1
    else:
        print("Incorrect! The answer is J!")
```

or

```
#Variables and Imports Declerations
import sys
import os
awnser = " "
score = 0
#----------------------------------

while playagin == "yes":

    #Welcome Message and Title
    print ("GeneralQuiz")
    print ("Welcome to GeneralQuiz!")

    #Question 1
    print ("What is the 10th letter of the alphabet?")
    answer.lower() = input ()

    if answer == "j":
        print ("Congratulations! + 1 Score!")
        score = score +1
    else:
        print("Incorrect! The answer is J!")
```

Comment: The problem lies in `answer.lower = something` you want `answer = something.lower()`

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you can't assign to a function call. `variable_name.lower()` is a function call.

You've put the call in the wrong place. You want to call it on the result of `input`:

```
variable_name = input().lower()
```

Comment: It runs now (after putting 

        answer = " "

between each question)

But now it has all questions after question 2 to be incorrect